# CMake Install directory files without keeping the full directory top

Tags: cmake

Let's say I have the directory X which includes many files and I want to install it to some destination:

```
INSTALL(DIRECTORY x
    Destination ${DEST}
)
```

When I run this command, the folder structure would look like this:

${DEST}/x/a

${DEST}/x/b

${DEST}/x/c

...

How can I make CMake to "Unpack" the directory structure and my output like this?

${DEST}/a

${DEST}/b

${DEST}/c

...

Answer (score 4):

When you append a `/` to your directory `x` the contents of the directory is copied to the `DESTINATION`, i.e.

```
install(DIRECTORY x/
    DESTINATION ${DEST}
)
```

The `DESTINATION` keyword has to be given upper case.

See CMake's [install documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html?highlight=install%20directory#installing-directories) for further details.